# What are the use cases for clang::acquire_capability?

Tags: c++, attributes, clang, pragma

clang supports the attribute [((acquire_capability))](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#acquire-capability-acquire-shared-capability-clang-acquire-capability-clang-acquire-shared-capability) for functions.
The only description they have for it is the following:

> "Marks a function as acquiring a capability."

What does a "capability" mean,  and what would be the use cases for this attribute?
Could someone provide an example of when a developer would use this?
I think it has something to do with multithreading, but I don't understand how it would be used.

Comment: Certainly none in the C language! Don't spam tags!

Comment: @Olaf I don't even know what it is.  A lot of these attributes do apply to C code as well.  That's why I added the tag.

Comment: @Olaf I did read the manual.  It wasn't in there.  That's why I asked the question.

Comment: Hmm, a simple search popped up various entries. Not sure if they help, but at least that might be a start. And check the manual not only for the attribute, but the concept!

Answer (score 1):

These attributes are code annotations to be used in conjunction with clang's thread-safety static analysis option: 
 https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html